Connecting AWS CloudFront to a vpc endpoint
I have read lots of discussions, AWS authored technical documents, and user examples on connecting to a VPC endpoint between regions.  I have yet to see anything involving CloudFront.
CloudFront exists in us-east-1 region and sending traffic to a vpc interface endpoint in another region is proving difficult.
You can assume I have read almost every article available from aws on this. I cannot get this over the line.  Does anyone have any insights or "gotchas" as to what I could be missing?

I have verified connection from CloudFront to the Public NLB directly works fine.  My hello world is displayed in my browser as expected.
If I switch out the NLB DNS address for the vpc endpoint dns address I get a 502 error "Request could not be satisfied".
I have enabled dns resolution and dns hostnames on both VPC's of the peering connection.
For the peering connection I have allowed both the requester and accepter to resolve DNS of hosts to the private IP address.
I have added a route in both directions to send traffic destined for the peered VPC over the peering connection.
I have tried using a CNAME rather than an A / Alias record to the VPC endpoint.
Thanks in advance for those that offer any advice.

Amazon CloudFront exists on the Internet, not in a VPC. CloudFront cannot use a VPC Endpoint. What is your actual goal? (That is, can you tell us what you want to achieve, rather than how you want to achieve it?)

Thanks for replying John.
I want to direct traffic form CloudFront through to an internal NLB that is balancing traffic to a ROSA cluster.
At the moment I am achieving this by:    CloudFront -> Public NLB -> Internal NLB -> ROSA Cluster.
I was hoping to change this to:     CloudFront -> VPC Endpoint -> Internal NLB -> ROSA Cluster

No, you cannot do this. VPC Endpoints are not accessible from outside of a VPC.

Thanks John - no wonder I couldn't get it to work

@JohnRotenstein if you don't mind me asking, (and hoping you know Azure a little as well) - but Azure Front Door provides the ability to connect to a internal load balancer via a private link. (see 4min in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r93x4lLPk6E).   Thought CloudFront would be the AWS equivalent here which is why I initially figured connecting to the vpc endpoint would be possible.  Is this highlighting the fact that Front Door has additional capabilities over CloudFront?

Sorry, but I don't know Azure services.

You are trying to compare features between Cloud to Cloud is not relevant here, what the community here is to help you solve your issue, not your architecture - some systems even have more and more network hops than yours. Basically, CloudFront origin requires an internet facing endpoint.
